# Xcode Interface Builder - margin between subviews according to data

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I've got a question while building an iOS custom view using Xcode's Interface Builder. Here's the situation;

My App has a custom view which shows an information of a single product; it shows product's name, brand name of the product, and its price. While name and price of the product are essential and is guaranteed to be given from API, brand name can be optional and be omitted from it.

Using the response from API the view shows the information as the following order if brand name exists:

```
product name
|----8px----|
brand name
|----8px----|
product price
```

and if not:

```
product name
|----8x----|
product price
```

which can be obtained from Interface Builder by 8px-wide layout constraint to product name label & brand name label, and to brand name label & product price label.

This layout will have no problem when the brand name is contained from the API response. If not, the brand name label will be hidden (which is normal), and product name label & product price label will have unwanted 16px-wide layout constraint, as such:

```
product name
|----8px----|
(no content)  => makes unwanted additional 8px-padding between two views
|----8px----|
product price
```

I know that selectively set layout constraint's constant value can be done in code (by referencing the target constraints, which is just too tedious), but is there a workaround to implement it in the Interface Builder editor?

Comment: use a UIStackView if you can, has this type of functionality built in

Comment: @Fonix unfortunately cannot, since the App's minimum deployment target is iOS 6.

Comment: heh then i dont think there is much you can do besides manually setting the one margin to 0 height. you could make some kind of helper method/object that could make it a bit less painful though

Comment: @Tack-GyuLee is this a new app or an old app modification? Supporting iOS 6 at this point is going to offer no value. Typical rule of thumb with iOS is to support the current release and the previous, as iOS users are far more likely to upgrade.

Comment: @Simon It isn't new, and sadly updating deployment target is not going to happen soon as my company is not a dev-centered one... but thanks for advice though.